# Enable eclipse Context menu item when the string that is right clicked exists in a map

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

We have a map composed of String. We right click a word in CEditor. there shows open decleration F3. We put an alternative context command that opens a help web page based on the word right clicked. At this point we want to enable the context menu command if this right clicked word exists in a map datastructure. So if a word doesnt exist in map the context menu will not show the command.

What I have done so far is define the command handlers and key binding. I think I need to use "activeWhen", right ? Can I use the "test" for this if so how ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: http://blog.sdruskat.net/control-visibility-of-menu-contributions-on-text-selection-with-propertytesters/ I found this.

Comment: I used handler so I extended my new command class from AbstractHandler. In AbstractHandler there is isEnabled method to override and to enable disable the command. I wonder how to implement the activeWhen ...